# How to Remove Shared Preference Values in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to clear value stored in Shared preferences 
I am using this code.

```
/*  SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();   */
```

but getting this error.

```
The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

private OnClickListener logoBarListener = new OnClickListener() {
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
         */
        public void onClick(View v) {

```
        if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_home) {

            showProgressBar(MainScreen.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_basket) {

            showProgressBar(ShopBasketGet.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_notification) {

            showProgressBar(Notification.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_login) {
            SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();   

            showProgressBar();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what Shaiful said is right.Try using YourActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating object of your LinearLayout class in Activity class then you should pass
Context in the Constructor.

Below is snipper

**Activity Class**

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
     {
         MyLinearLayout layout = new MyLinearLayout(this); 
         -----
         -----
     }  
}
```

**MyLinearLayout Class**

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private Context context;
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context; 
        SharedPreferences preferences=context.getSharedPreference("pref",
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this` keyword (Change `this.getSharedPreferences()` to `getSharedPreferences()`. `this` refers to the inner class of `View.onClickListener()`, while the method is actually in Activity class.

Comment: Try the method `Shabbir Panjesha` wrote above. One more question - Your class extends Activity, right?

Comment: public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
 SharedPreferences preferences;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

 public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
    context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  editor = preferences.edit();
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 SharedPreferences pref = YourActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 pref.edit().clear().commit();
```

i think u are try to clear onclick event than use this way

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: are u try to use sharedpreference in activity or in simple java class or in adapter class@NiteshKabra

Answer (score 0):

Use following code snippet

```
    Context context=YourActivityName.this;
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
```

Hope this helps,

Vipul

Comment: its also not working. as my class not extending Activity.it is extending Linear Layout.

Comment: If you calling Your class constructor from your activity then You must pass context to this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Call clearSharedPreferences() method from your button click and pass class variable context to this method

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
            this.context = context;
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void clearSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

//your code will become

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_home) {

            showProgressBar(MainScreen.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_basket) {

            showProgressBar(ShopBasketGet.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_notification) {

            showProgressBar(Notification.class);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.img_bottom_login) {
            clearSharedPreferences(context);
            showProgressBar();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Examples for remove sharedPreference, one var or all sharedPreference...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mysharedpreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
// a specific var of sharedPreference....
//Mark in the editor that a preference value should be removed, which will be done in the actual preferences once commit() is called.
editor.remove("mySharedVar");

//if you want remove all sharedPreference...
//Mark in the editor to remove all values from the preferences. Once commit is called, the only remaining preferences will be any that you have defined in this editor.
editor.clear();

editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bunch of codes please. These lines worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you too. ^_^

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.clear();
editor.apply();
```